# Colors don't show on a custom class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
 Expanded(
               //flex: 2,
               child: Row(
             children: <Widget>[
               Expanded(child: Reuseable(colour: Color(0xBAD681))),
               Expanded(
                   child: Reuseable(colour: Color(0xBAD681)),
                   )
             ],
           )),

   class Reuseable extends StatelessWidget {
   Reuseable({@required this.colour, this.cardChild});

   final Color colour;
   final Widget cardChild;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
       child: cardChild,
       margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         border: Border.all(
           color: Colors.grey,
         ),
           color: colour,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),.
     );
  }
 }
```

This is part of the code I have used to create a custom class which I can't color for some reason !! If there was no border the Reusable classes  would be invisible, any ideas why and how to fix it?

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/pyMnVgJ/Screenshot-1592356692.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a const variable which holds the color of the custom class widgets

```
const activeCardColour = Color(0xFF1D1E33);


 Expanded(
           //flex: 2,
           child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(child: Reuseable(colour: activeCardColour)),
           Expanded(
               child: Reuseable(colour: activeCardColour),
               )
         ],
       )),
```

Answer (score 0):

you Cannot provide both a color and a decoration
The color argument is just a shorthand for `"decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color)"`.

Remove the `color` parameter from the `Container` and leave the one in  `BoxDecoration:`

and then check for color null in `decoration`

`color: (this.colour != null)? this.colour: Colors.grey),`

**EDIT**
change `color:colour` to `color:this.colour`

Comment: Hello @griffins, I am not sure if you get it correctly. The color in the decoration was for the border not for the widget! The color that I a talking about is a parameter in 'Reusable class' However, it won't show color even I make it like this https://i.ibb.co/hFFf9km/Screenshot-from-2020-06-17-06-37-54.png

Comment: i have updated my answer ,if it works for you dont forget to mark as answer